# Induced map on Picard groups of curves under pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X \to Y$ be a degree 2 etale cover of smooth projective geometrically connected curves over some field. Consider the induced map on their Picard schemes. This map is never injective; in fact the covering classifies a nontrivial line bundle on $Y$ together with a trivialization of its square, and this bundle pulls back to the trivial bundle on $X$.

The question is: are there any more line bundles on $Y$ trivialized under pullback? Note that there are only finitely many because they are all forced to be 2-torsion.

Comment: No, there is only one such. If $f$ is the map, $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L$, where $L$ is your 2-torsion line bundle which becomes trivial above. If an $M$ has the same property, then $f_*f^*M=f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ and since $f_*f^*M=M\otimes (f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$, you get $M\oplus M\otimes L=\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L$ and the rest is easy.